# Reuse Swift Code between project, running framework code locally and via Carthage

Tags: git, git-submodules, carthage

Currently we have two Swift/XCode projects with some shared code. We currently use git submodules which works ok, but we're investigating if we can use Carthage to simplify/unify the use of frameworks/shared code. However, I am having trouble setting up a shared library and be able to run the shared code locally and at the same time test the framework+code build and fetched from Bitbucket via Carthage. Since I both have code fetched via Carthage (in the `Build` folder) as well as the original shared code placed in a separate folder. My questions are:

1. Which framework do I refer to from my non-shared-code XCode project? If I reference the local project, Carthage is not used. If I reference the code and framework in `Carthage/Checkouts` and `Carthage/Build` I guess I will run into issues when I want to change the shared-code. Or am I supposed to merge these folders into one (`Cartage/Build`)?
2. Can Git/Carthage similar to Git submodules automatically point to different commits in the shared-code-project? I see that Carthage allows you to point to a specific commit or version, but I guess I need to manually update this every time I modify the shared code? Feels cumbersome!

Is these to issues possible to solve? Or should we stick with Git submodules?